# Date Format in SQL Server keep coming out the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a field ADATE which is a varchar(8) and it's in the following format:yyyymmdd (20080402)

i want to make it look like:
4/2/2008

i tried the following:

```
select convert(varchar(8),adate,101) from myTable
 where  
AYEAR= ISNULL('2008', ayear)
and active = 'y'
```

but the result is still:

> 20080402

if i change the convert statement to:

```
convert(date,adate,101)
```

i always get:

> 2008-04-02

no matter what i change the format digit to.

what am i missing?

Comment: exactly how could `'2008'` ever **BE** null? what is the point of that part of the where clause?

Comment: 2008 is something 'm passing in as a parameter, i wrote it out here just for the examples sake. not sure why you are picking my query apart, that where clause is not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `convert` the `aDate` to a `datetime` first, then you can convert it to the format that you want:

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast(adate as datetime), 101)
from myTable
where AYEAR= ISNULL('2008', ayear)
  and active = 'y'
```

or:

```
select convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, adate), 101)
from myTable
where AYEAR= ISNULL('2008', ayear)
  and active = 'y'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bc9f3/5)

Comment: wow,every time i come back here you post more and more in the answer. thank you! i appreciate your help! didn't realize i had to convert it twice to get it to work. i guess a follow up question is: does it matter if i do cast or convert?

Comment: @TanyaXrum You can use either `cast` or `convert`, I posted both versions so you could see that either one with work.

Comment: also if you have the date datatype (sql 2008 => I believe), use that rather than the datetime, as the time part is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Syn123 I used `datetime` since they did not specify what version of sql server but if it is 2008+, then you can cast to date.

Comment: yep, he's using the date type in his code, otherwise I wouldn't have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

The first time around, you're formatting a string into a date, the 2nd time around, you're formatting the date back into a string, so combine them:

```
select convert(varchar(10), convert(date, adate), 101)
```